# MYSQL copy row to another identical table with AUTO_INCREMENT id field

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, row, auto-increment

I have a movie database where movies are inserted into a table named titles with an AUTO_INCREMENT primary key named titles_id. Users can submit movies anonymously which are inserted into a separate identical table named titles_anon. After reviewing entries in titles_anon I want to insert them into titles but the id column is causing problems

I tried this:

> INSERT INTO titles SELECT * FROM titles_anon WHERE
>   title_id='$title_id';

I either get a duplicate key error, or if the title_id does not already exist in titles it inserts OK but uses the titles_anon id instead of a new AUTO_INCREMENT value which I want.

How do I copy a row between tables when both tables have an AUTO_INCREMENT primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO titles 
(column_name1, column_name2, column_name3, column_name4,...)
SELECT title_id, col2, col3, col4,..
FROM titles_anon
WHERE title_id = '$title_id';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the `id` column completely, let mysql generate it for you. This need a little longer SQL to specify the exact columns you want to insert.

```
INSERT INTO titles (columns-other-than-the-primary-key) 
    SELECT columns-of-the-same-order FROM titles_anon
```

Answer (score 0):

You define your fields in SELECT, but omit the PK and add the same fields to INSERT!

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can do something similar to:

```
$rs = mysql_query("select * from table_orig where RowID=$IDToCopy",$db_conn);
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
 $sql = '';
 $fields = '';
 foreach($row as $k => $v){
  if($k == "RowID") continue;
  $sql .= ",'$v'";
  $fields .= ",$k";
 }
 $sql = "insert into table_copy (".substr($fields,1).") values (".substr($sql,1).")";
 mysql_query($sql,$db_conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

> /* copy table with primary key to another table */
>
> $table_old='colaboradores';  // your table old
>
> $table_new='colaboradores2'; //your table new
>
> // sql all columns withou primary key (column_key <> 'pri'
>
> $rs=mysql_query("select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
> where table_name = '$table_old' and column_key <> 'pri' AND
> table_schema = 'your database'");
>
> // get all columns
>
> $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
>
> $fields = '';
>
> // mount fields in line 
> foreach ($rows as $k => $v) {   
> $fields .= ",$v[0]"; 
> }
>
> // remove first comma 
> $fields = substr($fields,1);
>
> echo "Sintaxe for Create table in Mysql";
> echo "CREATE TABLE $table_new SELECT $fields FROM $table_old ";
> echo "Sintaxe for Insert from old table to new table Mysql"; 
> echo "INSERT INTO $table_new $fields SELECT $fields FROM $table_old";

Comment: Just some code? Don't you want to comment your answer?